# In UiPath, can I use an if loop when automating inputting data from Excel table into a website?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I am currently trying to input updated supplier data into a website. Currently what I am trying to do is if the address section is blank for a supplier, move on to the next item, otherwise fill out the address in the excel file and delete the secondary address line that is right below it.

I am trying to do this in an if loop shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: What appears to be the issue? Also, take a loot at the For Each Row activity: https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/for-each-row. Read a workbook's range into a datatable first using the Read Range activity.

Comment: What you try to do. Tell us the website.